# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am running a spree app.

I am getting below error when I try to add any product in the cart.

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This error comes only when I add `option types` and `variants` of the same product.

I am not sure what's exactly going wrong here, because I am not doing any changes in the code or something.

This is the extracted source it shows.

```
   if quantity.between?(1, 2_147_483_647)
    begin
      order.contents.add(variant, quantity, options)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      error = e.record.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    end
```

Here's my order controller's `populate` function.

```
# Adds a new item to the order (creating a new order if none already exists)
def populate
  order    = current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true)
  variant  = Spree::Variant.find(params[:variant_id])
  quantity = params[:quantity].to_i
  options  = params[:options] || {}

  # 2,147,483,647 is crazy. See issue #2695.
  if quantity.between?(1, 2_147_483_647)
    begin
      order.contents.add(variant, quantity, options)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      error = e.record.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    end
  else
    error = Spree.t(:please_enter_reasonable_quantity)
  end

  if error
    flash[:error] = error
    redirect_back_or_default(spree.root_path)
  else
    respond_with(order) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_path }
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace? Especially, where does this error happen and the code with line number where it happens?

Comment: Are you sure `variant`, `quantity`, `options` are all non-nil values?

Comment: @AnthonyE I added a product, then options as `select size` and then I added two variants for it as `500 gms` and `750gms` and I increased their quantity in the stock.

So possibly they are non-nil values

Comment: @born4new

`app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb:49:in `populate'
` this

Comment: Helps us to help you: please post the add method of the Content model, specify which line is the line 49, and show us some code so that we can understand what's going on!

Comment: @born4new edited and added the code there.

Comment: Thanks, what about the `add` method of the `Content` model? Is it a spree method or is it one you have? If you do, please post it as well.

Comment: It is a spree method

Comment: I will post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the values of `variant`, `quantity` and `options` before sending them to spree.

The fact that you get this error could be considered as a bug on their side, since you'd expect a nice error message saying "`variant` is nil" or the like.

To fix your problem though, I'd check that these values are valid ones before sending them to spree.

Answer (score 0):

**For future views about this issue.**

Check if the Variant cost_currency attribute is the same that is configured in Spree. You can check it in a rails console doing:

```
Spree::Config.get(:currency)
```

Sometimes it happens when spree is initialized with some currency by default and then the default currency is changed.